# Strange behavior of Mathematica regarding calculation time

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, timing

Today I witnessed the following strange behavior of *Mathematica*, when it comes to calculation time involving larger nested lists. The following is the short example that I setup, I am sure one can reproduce that behavior with other functions:

```
div[x_] := (RotateLeft[#, {1, 0}] - #) & @ x[[;; , ;; , 1]] + (RotateLeft[#, {0, 1}] - #) & @ x[[;; , ;; , 2]]
```

Which is some kind of discrete divergence operator, but this does not really matter here. And then I defined the corresponding lists to be evaluated by `div`:

```
testArray = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 256}, {j, 1, 256}];
testArray2D = Table[{testArray[[i, j]], testArray[[j, i]]}, {i, Dimensions[testArray][[1]]}, {j, Dimensions[testArray][[2]]}];
testArray2Dnew = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, 256}, {j, 1, 256}];
```

It is obvious, that `testArray2D` and `testArray2Dnew` should be pretty much identical from a numerical standpoint (i.e. same dimensions, same kind of numbers and same precision).
But when I apply `div` on both of them I get completely different calculation times:

```
Timing[div[testArray2D];]
```

delivers 0.035085 seconds and

```
Timing[div[testArray2Dnew];]
```

delivers 0.006100 seconds

Executing the above Timing commands over and over again does not change the results, so there is about a factor of 6 regarding calculation time.

Can somebody explain that behavior to me, because right now I am just confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this difference in timing (and memory usage) is that `testArray2Dnew` is packed array:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[testArray]
Developer`PackedArrayQ[testArray2D]
Developer`PackedArrayQ[testArray2Dnew]
(*
True
False
True
*)
```

[Packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) are an efficient way to store machine precision numerical data of the same type. In the documentation `ToPackedArray` is a starting point. If an internal function e.g. `RotateLeft` sees that it can make use of efficient code.